# get column index and row index for a cell, in a table

Tags: javascript

in JS, how can I retrieve the column & row index; given the cell index, and the width (colCount) & height (rowCount) of the table ?

eg.

```
var cellIndex = 11;
var colCount = 3;
var rowCount = 5;

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
|10 | X |12 |
|13 |14 |15 |

//should return
colIndex = 2;
rowIndex = 4;
```

eg.

```
var cellIndex = 8;
var colCount = 4;
var rowCount = 4;

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | X |
| 9 |10 |11 |12 |
|13 |14 |15 |16 |

//should return
colIndex = 4;
rowIndex = 2;
```

Thanks !

Comment: In the first example, shouldn't `rowIndex=4`?

Answer (score 2):

The indices can be calculated as follows.

```
rowIndex = ( ( cellIndex - 1 ) / colCount ) + 1;
colIndex = ( ( cellIndex - 1 ) % colCount ) + 1;
```

Note that `rowCount` is not necessary for the calculation.